# Is there a way to combine two words with one word having 'p' has the start, and the other having 'p' as the end, technically

Tags: regex

I've been wondering about this for a long, long time.

***Note:*** *This is not useful in anyway unless it is said to be useful by someone... But, I am just wondering if you can write this regex in a weird complicated way:*

```
/^(webp|p(?:ng|hotoshop))$/gm
```

Can you combine the two 'p's for web'p' and 'p'ng/hotoshop?

Remember *it* should only match:

```
webp
png
photoshop
```

I just couldn't find anything related to this, and I have no idea what to *google* to know about this.

To my understanding, this must not be possible in regex unless, this happens, ofcourse the below doesn't happen unless you mess with your fonts, really:
[image: regex fun]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those regex flavors that support [conditional regex constructs](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html), you can use

```php
^(web)?p(?(1)$|(?:ng|hotoshop))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yikmGO/1/).

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(web)?` - Group 1 (optional): - `web` string, 1 or 0 times
- `p`  - a `p`
- `(?(1)$|(?:ng|hotoshop))` - If Group 1 matched, match the end of string, else, match `ng` or `hotoshop`
- `$` - end of string.